# How to make android edittext fields visible when keyboard is open?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-animation, android-softkeyboard

In my android app, on the login page, there are two edittext fields username,password. The problem is when I click on password, the keyboard pops up and then most of the password field gets covered by the keyboard.

I want to basically have an animation that moves the two fields up (smoothly) when the keyboard pops up, and when the keyboard goes away, the fields should go back down smoothly. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Also I want to avoid putting in fixed amount of pixels to move, because then it will be device dependent. If possible maybe use something like ems units, so it works for all screen densities.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" to your login page's activity entry in the manifest?

Answer (score 2):

To do this you have to implement **addOnGlobalLayoutLitener. Wrap up the whole child view using scrollview and then scroll the layout. Test your app by changing the scrolling value. 
**

```
final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.signinRootView);
        activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView()
                                .getHeight() - activityRootView.getHeight();
                        if (heightDiff > 100) {
                            ((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollview))
                                    .scrollTo(0, findViewById(R.id.et_password)
                                            .getBottom() + 80);
                        } else
                            ((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollview))
                                    .scrollTo(0, 0);
                    }
                });
```

**